# Subclipse installation fails: SVN preferences visible, but nothing else (e.g. anything in contextual Team submenu). What is missing?

Tags: ubuntu, subclipse

I have attempted to install Subclipse, but even after attempts I still can't use its functionality. The failure this time is that, while the preferences panel is accessible and does list JavaHL, no other UI seems to be meaningfully accessible. For instance, while I can dd the "SVN Annotate" view, I cannot find any Show Annotation in the Team submenu of a file's contextual menu, even though this is what the SVN Annotate view tells I should be doing.

Using:
- Subclipse SVN Team Provider Core  4.2.4.201804261743  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse
# in order to use the platform-provided JavaHL JNI libraries:
- JavaHL (JNI) 1.9.7 (r1800392)
- Eclipse CDT Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
- Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had created the Eclipse project on a subfolder of the Subversion checkout, not on the top folder of the checkout. Now this is fixed I am able to access Subversion/Subclipse features on the project navigator.

Comment: I feel silly. Worst thing is, I had already written up the question, but not submitted it, when I thought to double-check that. And now that it's written up, well, might as well make that a public teachable moment…